# Laravel 10 + Sail + Breeze: Tailwind missing classes

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-breeze

In a brand new Laravel 10 project, based on the Breeze blade starter theme, I simply try to change the text color on the welcome screen, but it does not work.
I replace in `welcome.blade.php`at one of the paragraphs `text-gray-500` with `text-blue-500`, and expect to see blue text.
Instead, the browser renders the text in its default black, because the `text-blue-500`css class does not exist. I expected the Vite server, which is running in the background, to take care of this... What am I missing here?

To reproduce under Linux, simply run this:

```bash
curl -s https://laravel.build/l10 | bash
cd l10
./vendor/bin/sail up -d
./vendor/bin/sail composer require laravel/breeze --dev
 ./vendor/bin/sail artisan breeze:install
# Now select 0 for Blade, and No, No for the other 2 questions
./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
./vendor/bin/sail npm i
./vendor/bin/sail npm run dev
```

Changing the styles with classes that already exist in the template is no problem, but adding in new Tailwind classes does not work.

Also, when running `./vendor/bin/sail npm run build`, I can see that a css file is created under `public/build/assets`, and that file actually includes the text-blue-500 class. However that file does not seem to be used on the localhost server...
When using the Vue template, and making that same color change in the `Welcome.vue` file, it works without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `sail npm run build` each time you use some new Tailwind classes. This will compile the new classes into `public/build/assets/app-**.css`. Once done, the request to Sail’s localhost port should work as expected.

Comment: Then every change in a blade design implies a new "compilation"? It makes the work more difficult and slower. Is there any way to use Bootstrap?